# Javascript onclick event triggering on page load

Tags: javascript

I have the following html/javascript:

```
<div id="clickMe" style="width:200px;height:100px;background-color:red;">
click me
</div>

<script>
function bar(){
    alert("foo");
}

document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = bar();
</script>
```

When I load this page, the function triggers and the alert pops up, and then it doesn't trigger when I click `clickMe`. I tried switching the `div` out for a `button` and that worked fine (didn't trigger on page load, did trigger on click). When I comment out `document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = bar();`, the function doesn't trigger at all. I also tried adding `onload` functions surrounding the whole thing, and just the function, and just the trigger, to no great effect.

How do I trigger a javascript function by clicking on a div, and why is this not working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from the function name (doing so invokes it):

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = bar;
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H4jrU/)

Comment: -_- I guessed it was a syntax error, didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks.